# How to remove update packages in WSUS from database without built-in cleanup

Tags: windows, powershell

I am faced with the issue of hitting RAM-issues for my WSUS server. The problem situates in the fact that the database hase 23k+ updates in the database while most of them are superseded by newer updates or just not useful in my network. Now I can filter out the non-useful updates out from this point on but there is still the issue of the ever increasing amount of updates in the database.

When I try to use the built-in Server Cleanup Wizard the server node just crashes when it comes to actually deleting the unused/declined updates.

In order to to find a way to circumvent the Wizard I tried using powershell/batch scripts to remove the updates from the database but this is without success.

These are the following scripts I tried to use:

Powershell:

```
# Connecting to WSUS-server
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")

try {
    $wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer('WSUSServer', $False)
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error in connection to WSUS-Server: $_"
    exit
}

# Creating variable UpdateScope to specify the scope of updates
$updateScope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope

# Specifying the criteria of the UpdateScope base on date(unused)
# $updateScope.FromArrivalDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)  # Updates van de laatste 30 dagen

# Get declined updates with the use of UpdateScope
$declinedUpdates = $wsus.GetUpdates($updateScope)

# Counter for keeping track of removed updates
$removedUpdatesCount = 0

# Batchvalue to only remove the first 100 declined updates
$batchValue = 100

# Remove the decline updates
foreach ($update in $declinedUpdates) {
    if ($removedUpdatesCount -ge $batchValue) {
        break  # Break the loop if batchlimit has been reached
    }

    Write-Host "Removing update: $($update.Title)"
    & "C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\wsusutil.exe" deletefrontendcache $($update.Id.UpdateId)
    if ($?) {
        $removedUpdatesCount++
        Write-Host "Removed updates: $removedUpdatesCount"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Error during removing update: $($update.Title)"
    }
}

Write-Host "Removal of declined updates has been completed."
```

Batch:

When I use these scripts I get the following errors:

```
Unknown command. The following commands are known:
        help
        checkhealth
        configuressl
        configuresslproxy
        csaimport
        deletefrontendserver
        listinactiveapprovals
        removeinactiveapprovals
        export
        healthmonitoring
        import
        listfrontendservers
        listunreferencedpackagefolders
        movecontent
        refreshmuurl
        reset
        usecustomwebsite
        postinstall
```

In those known commands I don't see any possible way for me to remove declined updates and only the possibility to remove inactive approvals which is not what I am going for.

So does anyone have anyone have any idea as to how I can go about removing about 20k worth up updates, preferably in batches as to not overload the host computer? If needed the host is a Windows 2016 Server with WSUS version: 10.0.14393.5127 .

Comment: If the built in tools crash and you're having memory errors, it might be a better option to deploy a new server on the "down" part of your upgrade cycle and let it pull new updates.

Unless you have a lot of excluded updates the data on WSUS is completly re-obtainable.

Comment: Well the issue is that adding a new server is a lengthy process because of the business sector I am in. So that wouldn't really be the solution my manager will want even if that would indeed be the better solution.

Comment: We ran WSUS on a standard PC (server OS) because if it went down it was not really hard to replace.   I would consider a test run a replacement in dev and replace the server in prod by formatting.